# Can not replace file in /system/fonts folder in Android rooted device

Tags: android, rooted-device

I try to replace **DroidSansFallback.ttf**  by  **myfont.ttf** in /sdcard like this

```
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream outs=new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        outs.writeBytes("mount -o rw,remount /system"+"\n");
        outs.writeBytes("cat /sdcard/myfont.ttf >> /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf"+"\n");
        outs.writeBytes("mount -o rw,remount /system"+"\n");
        outs.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can copy DroidSansFallback out to /sdcard by this way but can NOT copy back.
Please help if you know the correct way to replace DroidSansFallback font in rooted device.

Comment: First, this is generally a bad idea.  But one obvious issue is that you are using the append operator ">>" when you probably want a simple redirect ">".  Other issues would be if you actually have a hacked `su` usable in this way, and if the hardware of your device places additional requirements (outside of linux) to unlock the system partition for writing.

Comment: Thanks! It's work! my bad when use >>. Please make as your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have "read only" permission on `/system/fonts`

Try below:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "chmod 777 /system/font" });
// I have used 777 just for testing you can change as per your requirement
proc.waitFor();
```